# how to get tableView section header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

This may sound like a weird question as obviously there is always `viewForHeaderInSection` method available when working with tables in iOS.

However, to work with that function, one needs to reload the data of that table, something which I, in this case, want to avoid.

I have a button in my `UITableViewSectionHeader`, and I want to disable it on a certain point in my app - again - without having to reload the tableview data.
I tried to do that with this piece code:

```
let currentTable = self.playerTables![i] as! UITableView
let header = currentTable.headerViewForSection(0)! as UITableViewHeaderFooterView!
let view = header.contentView as UIView
view.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

my app crashes when running this code, as the `header` is nil when loading the contentView. It does initialize when I call the `currentTable.headerViewForSection(0)!` code, but is nil again at the very next line.

I have checked whether the section i'm referring to is correct or not, checked apple docs and google/so and have not been able to find any reference on accessing the section header in the way I want. **Is there a way?**

Comment: Assuming you don't have a large number of section headers, create them at viewDidLoad, then save in an array. When the system asks for one, you can pull it out of the array and not create it dynamically. Now they won't be re-used, and you can access the button whether the view is showing or not. I do this with tableViews vending settings all the time. [If this works for you I'll delete this comment and make it an answer.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `headerview` is not on the screen (not visible), you cannot reach to it.

Maybe storyboard can help you. Drag an `UIView` into the `tableview`. This will be your `headerview` and you can connect controls directly to the `UIViewController` and access them.

Also you don't need to use `viewForHeaderInSection` for this example.

[image: headerview in storyboard]